# Adding a resetting counter (reset on a column's value change) to a PLSQL line in a view

Tags: oracle, view, plsql

I am using PL SQL developer and Oracle 11g.  Here is my issue:

*EDIT*

It looks like using rank (partition by header number, line number order by date) works.

I would like to create a counter that changes each time a column has a different value than the last.  I need to be able to do this in a view (non-modifiable constraint).  The goal would be to use this counter to build a new unique key into that view.  Thus, I need to reset the 'counter' each time a line number changes in the planning table (see below).

I have 3 tables.  Under each table I have put some important columns:

Header
--headerNumber (unique)

Detail
--headerNumber (not unique)
--lineNumber (unique)

Planning lines
--headerNumber (not unique)
--lineNumber (not unique)
--some date

Into the planning lines table, there exist multiple lines, per line number as well.  I want to build into a view (this is a constraint, it must be a view) the ability to build a unique number off of the line number from planning.

Here is some example data:

```
Header (1 row):
Header Number = 1

Detail (2 rows)
Header Number = 1, LineNumber = 1
Header Number = 1, LineNumber = 2

Planning (4 rows)
Header Number = 1, Line number = 1, date = 01/01/14
Header Number = 1, Line number = 1, date = 01/02/14
Header Number = 1, Line Number = 2, date = 01/01/14
Header Number = 1, Line Number = 2, date = 01/03/14
```

Into the view I want it to look like this:

```
HeaderNumber   |   Line Number   |   'Counter' (What I am trying to create)
1              |        1        |       1
1              |        1        |       2  
1              |        2        |       1
1              |        2        |       2
```

Here are some final issues I have faced:

It does not appear as if I can use row number -- The view will contain multiple headers, and more importantly, row number seems to be built out of the entire select's contents -- thus I can't trim it.  Row number ends up counting 1,2,3,4 (row above).

Does anyone have an idea about how to build this into a select (to put into a view)?  I know this can be done by a procedure but I really need a view.

Regards,

Seriously Confused Man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have tried exactly when you say "row number" - do you mean `ROWNUM` or `row_number()`?

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
select headernumber, linenumber, 
       row_number() over (partition by headernumber order by linenumber)
          as counter
from   ...;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help -- I had used Rownum previous.  Also using rank seemed to work.  Let me try to use your code and see if it works (I will test and follow up)

Comment: Your code works too -- I think I like the behavior of RANK() more (to have gap for duplicates).   Thanks for this alternate option

Comment: `partition by` is what I was missing to have my counter reset